# I lose every battle in Dragon Front and don't know why. Any general guidelines?

Tags: dragon-front

I tried all 4 available factions, I tried building my own deck. I tried things.. But nevertheless, I always end up loosing. As if every opponent on earth is better than me. I want to believe that it's not the case.

Any general advise to have a better chance of wining some games ?

- what should be the ratio between low and high mana card ?
- what should be the ratio between spells / creatures ?
- should I try to defend at all cost ?
- should I try to attack ASAP ?
- should I try to block opponent's mana generation instead of building mine ?
- Am I just a desperate case ?
- ?..

I have really no clue about why I'm so bad at this game. Any general advice would be appreciated.

Or, is there actually any tips that can be given like that without more context ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most people familiar with modern CCGs assume that you get incremental mana at the start of the turn.

In fact, you get 1 mana each turn, and an additional mana for each unit you have stationed in your spawn row at the start of the turn. This means if your four space mana row is full, you will generate 5 mana at the start of your turn. You will see a blue highlight under the units that will be generating mana for you.

This design encourages you to keep your units back in your spawn row until you are comfortable with your mana growth. At that point send them to battle! Sending units across the battlefield too early in the match will surely put your mid-game mana generation at risk.

If you are one mana away from being able to afford a card, you have a few options. Once per turn, you can discard a card from your hand to generate one mana. Just remember having card options is equally powerful, so I would only do this in the early game, or if you REALLY need that 1 mana.

Also, when one of your units is destroyed you gain mana fragments. These are the tiny blue skulls on the right panel when you examine a card. This helps recover enough mana to bring out other units. In cases where you really need to bring out a higher costed card, sacrificing a unit is a great option! Remember the BLIGHT trait removes these fragments, earning you NOTHING for its death.

THORNS is a great faction for mana generation, with units, spells and forts that contribute mana.

SCALES - Command Headquarters in the Scale faction is one of the best Mana generating forts in the game.

STRIFE requires some finesse, as they have units that can spawn outside of their spawn row, which is great for aggressive gameplay, but hinders their mana generation.

ECLIPSE wins with its swarm tactics, easily filling the spawn row in the first couple turns of the game, creating strong and reliable mana generation. They also have the Soul Foundry fort to generate decent mana.

There are a few great unaligned cards that work in any faction. These are:
1.  Ice Leech – which gives you 1 mana for each unit in the enemy’s spawn row.
2.  Battlefield Surveyors – which give you 1 mana at the end of the turn, if they didn’t take an action.
3.  And if you are super aggressive, Spoils of War gives you 2 mana for each of your units in enemy territory.

Lastly, If you run into the fortunate case of having TOO MUCH mana, you can always bank some to your Champion to reduce its cost. Always try to make a mental calculation of how much mana you will have on your next turn. If this is over 10, BANK IT or lose it! Remember, you can never have more than 10 mana in your pool.